# How can I create a maven plugin to test the source code of a project?

Tags: java, maven, gitlab

We have a console program that checks all .java files in a project for some common mistakes. It Reads the source code as plain text. We'd like to transform it to a maven plugin that is run when pushed to gitlab in the CI pipeline

Comment: Why not use one of the Maven plugins that already exist? https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2018/03/how-to-run-checkstyle-pmd-and-findbugs-from-maven/

Comment: @SiKing already using pmd but there are some really specific cases from my company that are not covered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a description of writing Maven plugins here:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

You need to use the packaging `maven-plugin` and extend the `AbstractMojo` class.